# NPE when using JUL with SLF4J at trace level

Tags: java, jersey, logback, slf4j, java.util.logging

I have created a sample application by following the tutorial mentioned at [Creating a Basic REST Web Service using Grizzly, Jersey](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/griz_jersey_intro/Grizzly-Jersey-Intro.html#overview). I have extended the sample with logback.xml. I later found out that jersey uses java.util.logging and configured a slf4j bridge. Things are working fine but I get a unrecoverable exception when having logback level at trace and works fine when level is set at debug or higher (INFO, WARN etc).

Below is the stacktrace -

```
20:35:24.531 [grizzly-nio-kernel(7) SelectorRunner] WARN  o.g.g.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain - GRIZZLY0013: Exception during FilterChain execution
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at java.lang.String.<init>(String.java:166)
    at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:3008)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.FilterChainContext.toString(FilterChainContext.java:1076)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.subformat(MessageFormat.java:1280)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:865)
    at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:157)
    at java.text.MessageFormat.format(MessageFormat.java:841)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.getMessageI18N(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:265)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.callLocationAwareLogger(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:220)
    at org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler.publish(SLF4JBridgeHandler.java:303)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:738)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.doLog(Logger.java:765)
    at java.util.logging.Logger.log(Logger.java:851)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeFilter(DefaultFilterChain.java:280)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.executeChainPart(DefaultFilterChain.java:201)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:133)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.preClose(NIOConnection.java:879)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnection.preClose(TCPNIOConnection.java:97)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.terminate0(NIOConnection.java:603)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOConnection.terminate0(TCPNIOConnection.java:291)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection$4.completed(NIOConnection.java:567)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection$4.completed(NIOConnection.java:563)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.asyncqueue.AsyncWriteQueueRecord.notifyCompleteAndRecycle(AsyncWriteQueueRecord.java:173)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:279)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:169)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.write(AbstractNIOAsyncQueueWriter.java:71)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.AbstractWriter.write(AbstractWriter.java:76)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.closeGracefully0(NIOConnection.java:562)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.NIOConnection.closeWithReason(NIOConnection.java:513)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.execute(DefaultFilterChain.java:160)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.filterchain.DefaultFilterChain.process(DefaultFilterChain.java:112)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.ProcessorExecutor.execute(ProcessorExecutor.java:77)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOTransport.fireIOEvent(TCPNIOTransport.java:539)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOServerConnection$RegisterAcceptedChannelCompletionHandler.completed(TCPNIOServerConnection.java:353)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.transport.TCPNIOServerConnection$RegisterAcceptedChannelCompletionHandler.completed(TCPNIOServerConnection.java:320)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.registerChannel0(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:336)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.access$400(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:64)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler$RegisterChannelOperation.run(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:467)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTaskQueue(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:301)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.processPendingTasks(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:293)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.DefaultSelectorHandler.preSelect(DefaultSelectorHandler.java:101)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.doSelect(SelectorRunner.java:335)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.nio.SelectorRunner.run(SelectorRunner.java:279)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.doWork(AbstractThreadPool.java:593)
    at org.glassfish.grizzly.threadpool.AbstractThreadPool$Worker.run(AbstractThreadPool.java:573)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

My logging.properties file -

```
handlers = org.slf4j.bridge.SLF4JBridgeHandler
.level=ALL
java.util.logging.SLF4JBridgeHandler.level = ALL
```

My logback.xml file -

```
<configuration>

    <contextListener class="ch.qos.logback.classic.jul.LevelChangePropagator">
        <resetJUL>true</resetJUL>
    </contextListener>

    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <!-- encoders are assigned the type
             ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="trace">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

NOTE: I have the following in my main method if it makes any difference

```
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.removeHandlersForRootLogger();
    SLF4JBridgeHandler.install();
```

Comment: Do you actually have that line break in the configuration file?

Comment: @chrylis are you referring to logging.properties file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is bug [FilterChainContext.toString crashes with NullPointerException #1959](https://github.com/javaee/grizzly/issues/1959) in Grizzly.

> There are two overloads of String.valueOf, with Object and char[]. (Java 8)
> Because of the dangerous unbound generic in getMessage both overloads would seem applicable, however the char[] overload is chosen, probably because it is more specific.

> [snip]
>
> However String.valueOf(char[]) will fail if the result of getMessage is null.  I would assume a ClassCastException could happen in other cases. This can be fixed by explicitly casting the result to object or ensuring that the correct generics are infered.

You need to upgrade to a newer version of Grizzly (2.4.3).

A regression bug was filed in Nov 10, 2020 under: [FilterChainContext.toString causes NullPointerException #2110](https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/grizzly/issues/2110) which reports fixed in 4.0.0-M2-RELEASE.

Commit is listed as: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/grizzly/commit/d7a96f15083a55c38f63746007f664f1ede9f474

Comment: I had the latest version(2.26) of `jersey-container-grizzly2-http` which was transitively pulling version 2.4.0. Once I upgraded to grizzly version 2.4.3 the error went away.

Comment: I had to update form 3.1.0-M2 to 3.1.0-M7 to fix this Issue. I don't know why or when the issue was re-introduced, but I was getting the exact same stack trace.